# Удаление переменной сессии при закрытии страницы регистрации

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! На странице регистрации реализовано следующее: при отправке формы происходят всевозможные проверки, после чего данные в заполненных полях исчезали. С помощью сессионной переменной этого получилось избежать, данные сохраняются в полях, но если пользователь перейдёт на другую страницу сайта, а затем обратно вернётся на регистрацию, то данные по-прежнему останутся там. Как можно исправить это - чтобы после того, как пользователь закрыл страницу регистрации, то и переменная сессии также удалялась.

Answer (score 2):

ПО ХОРОШЕМУ
Подход в корне не верный, зачем по каждому пуку нагружать сервер ненужными операциями. Вот у Вас начался процесс регистрации -> пользователь вводит имя например, почту, еще что то -> Вы проверяете это на фронте с помощью JS на валидность, если есть поля например логин, который должен быть уникален-> то ajax запрос на сервер делаете с целью узнать свободен нет-> узнали, все гуд и хотите начать регистрацию на сервере, зная что данные годные-> тогда отправляется ajax запрос на сервер с целью регистрации-> сервер на всякий случай по своему это все проверил -> если все гуд записал в сессию нужные данные если требуется-> вернул на фронт что все гуд-> и двигаемся дальше или причину что не так,-> и фронт решает открыть след страницу или нет и выдать ошибку.

В сессии не должны хранится такие данные как вы сказали, морда от серверной части для того и отделена что бы не грузить сервак каждый раз, и самой выполнять обезьянью работу.

ПО ПЛОХОМУ
1.Заведи в сессии переменную "Последнее обращение к регистрации", куда фигач таймштамп при каждом обращении к регистрации.
2.Заведи в сессии переменную "успех регистрации", которая принимает true в случае если регистрация успешна.
3.Когда запускается скрипт регистрации смотришь на разницу  таймштампов если разница превышает например 30 минут, то данные старой сессии чистишь, если видишь успех регистрации то так же.

ПО ПЛОХОМУ
1. Каждый раз когда что то проверяешь передавай серверу гетом или постом флажок что это проверка.
2. Если флажка в запросе нет то значит нужно чистить данные регистрационной формы
3. Лучше флажок передавать постом

ЭТО КАСТЫЛИ И ЭТО ПЛОХО, таких костылей Вам могут тут написать много, и правильного не будет.
По хорошему тоже вариантов много, я поделился опытом.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о том, чтобы подставить данные в поля, если пользователь не прошел валидацию, то самый простой вариант, это вернуть результаты полученных данных от пользователя через GET/POST и подставить как выбранные значения в вашу форму. Сессия для этого вообще не нужно. Но это будет работать для простых форм. Если у вас пошаговая форма, можно перемещаться между шагами и т.п., это решение может не подойти, зависит от реализации.

Также, как вариант, ограничить время жизни сессии до небольшого значения, в рамках которого можно считать, что допустимо подставить заполненные ранее значения. Например, если прошло больше 3 минут, то сессия умирает. Если в рамках этого времени пользователь совершал переходы, то подставляем значения.

И еще простой, но костыльный вариант - обрабатывать все входящие запросы и проверять, если это не страница регистрации, то убивать соответствующую сессию. Но решение, честно говоря, так себе.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам "*приспичило*" хранить временные данные в сессии, то советую погуглить в сторону `FlashData` - этот механизм для разового получения данных. Во многих фреймворках эта плюшка доступна "*из коробки*". Если вы используете самописную основу сайта, то придется изобрести что-то похожее.

Answer (score 0):

Сохранить значение поля это значит выдать значение этого поля, которое было введено прошлый раз, и что самое важное - после проверки. Если пользователь уйдет со страницы регистрации, а затем вернется, то он не ожидает увидеть там значения полей. А вот если он отправит форму и получит ответ - то ожидает.

Самое простое решение - хранить значения полей "один раз", был уже ответ выше.

Опишу идею реализации на маленьком примере:

```
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();

$message = '<p>Так себе значение, я вам скажу</p>';

/* Ищем только в POST/GET */
$field = Param('field_name', false);
if ($field !== NULL) {
    /* Есть какое-то значение поля */
    if ($field == 'abc') {
        /* Хорошее значение - пишем об этом, проводим регистрацию, и переходим куда-нибудь */
        $message = '<p>Бинго! Значение просто великолепно!</p>';
        /* ... */
        /* В случае успеха перенаправления нет, поэтому хорошее значение будет заморожено */
    } else {
        /* В случае провала уничтожаем POST/GET перенаправлением на эту же страницу
         * Значения введенных полей будут взяты из сессии один раз, а POST-данные пропадут */
        header("HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily", true, 302);
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], true);
        exit();
    }
} else {
    /* Попытка поискать значение еще и в сессии */
    $field = Param('field_name', true);
}

print '<html>
<head>
<title>797252</title>
</head>
<body>
    '.$message.'
    <p>Значение <code>abc</code> считается хорошим, все остальные нет</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="field_name" value="'.$field.'">
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить форму">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
';

ob_flush();

/* Возвращает значение по имени из POST, если там нет, то из GET, а если и там нет, то при установленном флаге $use_cache ищет в SESSION['cache']
 * Вернет NULL, если такого значения нигде нет */
function Param($field_name, $use_cache)
{
    /* Не люблю Notice */
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cache'])) {
        $_SESSION['cache'] = array();
    }

    $value = NULL;
    if (isset($_POST[$field_name])) {
        /* Нашли в POST */
        $value = $_POST[$field_name];
        /* Кешируем */
        $_SESSION['cache'][$field_name] = $value;
    } else if (isset($_GET[$field_name])) {
        /* Нашли в GET */
        $value = $_GET[$field_name];
        /* Кешируем */
        $_SESSION['cache'][$field_name] = $value;
    } else if ($use_cache && isset($_SESSION['cache'][$field_name])) {
        /* Нашли в сессии */
        $value = $_SESSION['cache'][$field_name];
        /* Выбрасываем кеш, чтобы найти в сессии можно было только один раз */
        unset($_SESSION['cache'][$field_name]);
        $_SESSION['cache'][$field_name] = NULL;
    }

    /* Вообще нигде не нашли */
    return $value;
}

?>
```